# How to scroll to a specific option (that isn't selected) in a dropdown using Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, dropdown

I wonder if it is possible to scroll to a specific option (that isn't currently selected) in a dropdown. I mean I have a dropdown with years and I want to scroll to the current year in this dropdown. Selected item in the dropdown is the first option which is the label "Select year".
Is this possible as dropdown scrolls to the selected option and in my case current year is not selected.
Thanks.

Comment: No, I have dropdown and by default selected option is label "Select year". I want when user click on the dropdown and it is opened, to scroll to the year "2017". I don't have to use jquery.

Comment: Please add the previous comment to the question to make it clearer for others

Comment: I haven't deleted it. Please add it.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can. Steps in vanilla javascript:

You need to find the current year, so set the id of each year in the dropdown to that year.

Then query the DOM for the current year:

```
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
var currentYearElement = document.getElementById(currentYear.toString())
```

Scroll the current year to the top

```
currentYearElement.scrollTop = 0
```

If you're still having trouble, paste your code.

In general, you can also get the position of the element on the page via `getBoundingClientRect()`, which contains a `top` (how far down it is) property and others. `console.log` the value to see them. Then scroll to that position by doing this:

```
positions = element.getBoundingClientRect() 
document.scrollTo(0, positions.top) // arguments are x, y
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have to scroll not to "0" but to this option that is current year. How I could get the height?

Comment: I've tried to do that today, but it gave me the error that I cannot select option in this way. I've added `id` of each option and I tried to select it like that: `document.getElementById('#myDropdownName #2017')` and it gave me that error that isn't allowed selector.

Comment: getElementById takes in one id name so `document.getElementById('2017')` would be correct. If you get errors that sound like they have to do with syntax, search for examples of how these functions are used.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I've done it in this way: `document.querySelector('#myDropdownName #2017')`. I've think about another solution if I set selected option with value`2017` and if user close dropdown without choosing any option, to restore it and set selected "Select year"